# scraperjs : Code for web scraping not working

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am basically writing a small web scraping code. Initially I went for NodeJS+Request+Cheerio to scrape the website but then later I realized that Cheerio works only for Static web page not for those which load  DOM objects using JS.

So then I went for ScraperJS since it has the Static_Dynamic ContentScraper.
I have set up all the dependencies as specified here:https://github.com/ruipgil/scraperjs

But still my code is not working that is the sample code given on their github repository.
Platform : windows 7 , running through CMD : node file_name.js

Code :

```
var scraperjs = require('scraperjs');
    console.log("a2");
scraperjs.DynamicScraper.create('https://news.ycombinator.com/')
    .scrape(function($) {
        return $(".title a").map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();
    })
    .then(function(news) {
        console.log(news);
    })
```

Comment: How is it not working? What's the error returned?

Comment: @Veve its not returning any error. I run it using node hello.js and it just executes without printing anything and terminates. I am not able to debug what is happening behind scenes. It's the same code as given in ScraperJS Github account as Getting Started tutorial

Comment: It doesn't even output "a2"?

Comment: yaa thats it but  not the scraping part.

Comment: Yeah but then it's not "without printing anything"..

Comment: Did my response below provided an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/ruipgil/scraperjs/issues/57), it comes from phantomJS, which has to be downgraded in order to make the DynamicScraper working.

You have to downgrade phantomJS to version 1.9.8, or to use the 4.8 version of NodeJS.